# Compile and link a source file containing object files to another data structure

Tags: c, makefile

This is my current Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
INCLUDE=./Structures/
CFLAGS=-Wall -I$(INCLUDE)
OBJS=rlmain.o rlist.o queue.o

.PHONY: all clean

all: rlmain

queue.o: $(INCLUDE)queue.c $(INCLUDE)queue.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(INCLUDE)queue.c -o queue.o

rlist.o: $(INCLUDE)rlist.c $(INCLUDE)rlist.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(INCLUDE)rlist.c -o rlist.o

rlmain: main.c rlist.o queue.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c rlist.o queue.o -o rlmain

clean: 
        rm -f *.o rlmain
```

Makefile is in the top directory. In the lower directory called "Structures" is a collection of files for my data structures. My data structures implement a ready list - a linked list of queues.

I managed to get queue.o working using '-c' but I cannot get rlist.o to make because rlist.c does not contain a main method, and it must link to the queue.o functions. I'm using the command `make`

Everything else working except the command. I want to write a command to tell the compiler to link the queue.o functions to the rlist.c compilation but not compile the functions that require main(). What do I do in order to make that happen?

Comment: Source files don't contain object files by definition! Compilers don't link. See [ask], provide a [mcve].

Comment: You only need the final linking for `rlmain` not for `rlist.o`. Just compile `rlist.o` with `-c` as you do for `queue.o`. And then link them both in the final `rlmain` target.

Comment: but when I do that, it's saying rlist.o has undefined references to all of my queue functions

Comment: What more could you possibly need to answer a question Olaf...

Comment: @user3466773: That is a completely different issue. "What more could you possibly need to answer a question" - Let me think ... The actual error and the necessary information?

Comment: "when I do that". When you do what? You probably did "that" wrongly (you can't get undefined reference link errors with `-c` because by definition it doesn't link). So show exactly what you did and what the exact error message is if you want help. Because your "that" and what I think your "that" is could be very different.

Comment: First off, I know why the error happens if I don't include -c, and I specified it. Second, there's only a warning when I -c "gcc: warning: queue.o: linker input file unused because linking not done" and then I make the rlmain and I have undefined references to all of my queue.o functions. There shouldn't need to be any more information for how to do one technical operation that would help a few people with this issue, as embedded structures are a fairly common practice, but if there was a prior post I would not have made this one.

Comment: -c in rlist.o. then make rlmain, kaylum

Comment: Please, please update the question with the *exact* changes. For example, did you add `queue.o` to the `rlmain` build command? And remove `queue.o` from the `rlist.o` build command?

Comment: I didn't make any changes, kaylum. I'm saying I already tried what you told me to do but it did not work. I compiled rlist.o with a -c flag, then when I make rlmain it errs and says all my functions defined in queue.h are undefinded

Comment: You did make changes to try what I suggested. The fact is that it seems you did not make those changes in the correct way. But without seeing exactly what you tried we cannot  help you to progress further. But the general solution approach is the same - don't attempt to link until the final stage.

Comment: Alright, it was updated with my change I made

Comment: I already pointed out to you: add queue.o to the rlmain build command and remove queue.o from the rlist.o build command.

Comment: Well it looks like it compiled, so thank you, but shouldn't there be a problem compiling rlist.o if in rlist.c I'm calling functions defined in queue.h?

Comment: No. Because symbol resolution only happens at the link stage (without the `-c`). In the compilation phase any undefined symbols are marked but are not considered errors as that is the job of the later link phase to resolve.

Comment: from your question, it is obvious that each of the three compile operations (and you really should have 3 compile rules + 1 link rule)  each need to 1) source must #include each of the header files 2) the make file should list every 'user' header file that contains prototypes that are called within the associated source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Note: `<tab>` needs to be replaced with a tab character
Note: use `:=` when defining macros, so they are only evaluated once

# select the specific external executables to run
CC := /usr/bin/gcc
RM := /usr/bin/rm

INCLUDE := ./Structures/
CFLAGS  := -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu99 
OBJS    := main.o rlist.o queue.o

.PHONY: all clean

all: rlmain

queue.o: $(INCLUDE)queue.c $(INCS)
<tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -I$(INCLUDE)

rlist.o: $(INCLUDE)rlist.c $(INCS)
<tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -I$(INCLUDE)

main.o: $(INCLUDE)main.c $(INCS)
<tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -I$(INCLUDE)

rlmain: $(OBJS) 
<tab>$(CC) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS)

clean: 
<tab>$(RM) -f *.o rlmain
```

--EDIT-- following ADDED --
the following are some of the more common `GNU make` utility macros

```
$@  <<-- the name to the left of the colon on the `rule`

    The file name of the target.
$%

    The target member name, when the target is an archive member.
$<  <<-- I use this to reference the first dependency on the `rule`

    The name of the first prerequisite.
$?  <<-- a more reliable method to reference the first dependency on the `rule`

    The names of all the prerequisites that are newer than the target, with spaces between them. For prerequisites which are archive members, only the named member is used (see Archives).
$^
$+

    The names of all the prerequisites, with spaces between them. For prerequisites which are archive members, only the named member is used (see Archives). The value of $^ omits duplicate prerequisites, while $+ retains them and preserves their order.
$*

    The stem with which an implicit rule matches (see How Patterns Match).
$(@D)
$(@F)

    The directory part and the file-within-directory part of $@.
$(*D)
$(*F)

    The directory part and the file-within-directory part of $*.
$(%D)
$(%F)

    The directory part and the file-within-directory part of $%.
$(<D)
$(<F)

    The directory part and the file-within-directory part of $<.
$(^D)
$(^F)

    The directory part and the file-within-directory part of $^.
$(+D)
$(+F)

    The directory part and the file-within-directory part of $+.
$(?D)
$(?F)

    The directory part and the file-within-directory part of $?.
```

Comment: Thanks for the better practices, but what does $< mean?

Comment: The $ what ever macros are very useful.  I use the macros defined in the GNU MAKE utility.   download the full manual from: `https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/`    I have edited the answer to include some of the `make` 'shortcut' macros